# Query that took a lot of time in Postgresql when not using trim in order by

Tags: sql, postgresql, pentaho, mondrian

I have a query that produce a different query plan if I put a trim in one of the columns in the order by.

When i put the trim it use hashaggregate and took 3 seconds against 30 when not.

Is wear because the column is clean not need to be trimmed, I have check that.

The problem is that I can't change the query because is generate by the mondrian.

I do research and found in postgres list that I need to crank work_mem up high but don't work for me.

My postgresql.conf

```
# Add settings for extensions here
default_statistics_target = 50 # pgtune wizard 2014-06-04
maintenance_work_mem = 1GB # pgtune wizard 2014-06-04
constraint_exclusion = on # pgtune wizard 2014-06-04
checkpoint_completion_target = 0.9 # pgtune wizard 2014-06-04
effective_cache_size = 44GB # pgtune wizard 2014-06-04
#work_mem = 1536MB # pgtune wizard 2014-06-04
work_mem = 16GB
wal_buffers = 32MB # pgtune wizard 2014-06-04
checkpoint_segments = 16 # pgtune wizard 2014-06-04
shared_buffers = 15GB # pgtune wizard 2014-06-04
max_connections = 20 # pgtune wizard 2014-06-04
```

Query with trim

```
SELECT "dim_cliente"."tipocliente" AS "c0", 
       "dim_cliente"."a1_ibge" AS "c1", 
       "dim_cliente"."a1_cod" AS "c2", 
       "dim_cliente"."a1_nome" AS "c3", 
       "dim_vendedor"."a3_nome" AS "c4" 
  FROM "public"."dim_cliente" AS "dim_cliente", 
       "public"."fato_ventas_productos" AS "fato_ventas_productos", 
       "public"."dim_vendedor" AS "dim_vendedor" 
 WHERE "fato_ventas_productos"."key_cliente" = "dim_cliente"."key_cliente" 
   AND "fato_ventas_productos"."key_vendedor" = "dim_vendedor"."key_vendedor" 
 GROUP 
    BY "dim_cliente"."tipocliente" , 
       "dim_cliente"."a1_ibge", 
       "dim_cliente"."a1_cod", 
       "dim_cliente"."a1_nome", 
       "dim_vendedor"."a3_nome" 
 ORDER 
    BY trim("dim_cliente"."tipocliente") ASC NULLS LAST, 
       "dim_cliente"."a1_ibge" ASC NULLS LAST, -- the same result if I put the trim here
       "dim_cliente"."a1_cod" ASC NULLS LAST, -- or here
       "dim_cliente"."a1_nome" ASC NULLS LAST; -- or here
-- this query took 3845.895 ms
```

Query Plan when using trim

```
                                                                             QUERY PLAN                                                                              
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Sort  (cost=193101.41..195369.80 rows=907357 width=129) (actual time=3828.176..3831.261 rows=43615 loops=1)
   Output: dim_cliente.tipocliente, dim_cliente.a1_ibge, dim_cliente.a1_cod, dim_cliente.a1_nome, dim_vendedor.a3_nome, (btrim((dim_cliente.tipocliente)::text))
   Sort Key: (btrim((dim_cliente.tipocliente)::text)), dim_cliente.a1_ibge, dim_cliente.a1_cod, dim_cliente.a1_nome
   Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 13121kB
   ->  HashAggregate  (cost=91970.52..103312.49 rows=907357 width=129) (actual time=2462.690..2496.729 rows=43615 loops=1)
         Output: dim_cliente.tipocliente, dim_cliente.a1_ibge, dim_cliente.a1_cod, dim_cliente.a1_nome, dim_vendedor.a3_nome, btrim((dim_cliente.tipocliente)::text)
         ->  Hash Join  (cost=856.30..80628.56 rows=907357 width=129) (actual time=29.524..1533.880 rows=907357 loops=1)
               Output: dim_cliente.tipocliente, dim_cliente.a1_ibge, dim_cliente.a1_cod, dim_cliente.a1_nome, dim_vendedor.a3_nome
               Hash Cond: (fato_ventas_productos.key_vendedor = dim_vendedor.key_vendedor)
               ->  Hash Join  (cost=830.02..68126.13 rows=907357 width=86) (actual time=28.746..1183.691 rows=907357 loops=1)
                     Output: dim_cliente.tipocliente, dim_cliente.a1_ibge, dim_cliente.a1_cod, dim_cliente.a1_nome, fato_ventas_productos.key_vendedor
                     Hash Cond: (fato_ventas_productos.key_cliente = dim_cliente.key_cliente)
                     ->  Seq Scan on public.fato_ventas_productos  (cost=0.00..46880.57 rows=907357 width=16) (actual time=0.004..699.779 rows=907357 loops=1)
                           Output: fato_ventas_productos.key_cliente, fato_ventas_productos.key_vendedor
                     ->  Hash  (cost=618.90..618.90 rows=16890 width=86) (actual time=28.699..28.699 rows=16890 loops=1)
                           Output: dim_cliente.tipocliente, dim_cliente.a1_ibge, dim_cliente.a1_cod, dim_cliente.a1_nome, dim_cliente.key_cliente
                           Buckets: 2048  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 1980kB
                           ->  Seq Scan on public.dim_cliente  (cost=0.00..618.90 rows=16890 width=86) (actual time=0.008..16.537 rows=16890 loops=1)
                                 Output: dim_cliente.tipocliente, dim_cliente.a1_ibge, dim_cliente.a1_cod, dim_cliente.a1_nome, dim_cliente.key_cliente
               ->  Hash  (cost=18.90..18.90 rows=590 width=59) (actual time=0.747..0.747 rows=590 loops=1)
                     Output: dim_vendedor.a3_nome, dim_vendedor.key_vendedor
                     Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 56kB
                     ->  Seq Scan on public.dim_vendedor  (cost=0.00..18.90 rows=590 width=59) (actual time=0.026..0.423 rows=590 loops=1)
                           Output: dim_vendedor.a3_nome, dim_vendedor.key_vendedor
 Total runtime: 3845.895 ms
(25 filas)
```

Query without trim

```
SELECT "dim_cliente"."tipocliente" AS "c0", 
       "dim_cliente"."a1_ibge" AS "c1", 
       "dim_cliente"."a1_cod" AS "c2", 
       "dim_cliente"."a1_nome" AS "c3", 
       "dim_vendedor"."a3_nome" AS "c4" 
  FROM "public"."dim_cliente" AS "dim_cliente", 
       "public"."fato_ventas_productos" AS "fato_ventas_productos", 
       "public"."dim_vendedor" AS "dim_vendedor" 
 WHERE "fato_ventas_productos"."key_cliente" = "dim_cliente"."key_cliente" 
   AND "fato_ventas_productos"."key_vendedor" = "dim_vendedor"."key_vendedor" 
 GROUP 
    BY "dim_cliente"."tipocliente" , 
       "dim_cliente"."a1_ibge", 
       "dim_cliente"."a1_cod", 
       "dim_cliente"."a1_nome", 
       "dim_vendedor"."a3_nome" 
 ORDER 
    BY "dim_cliente"."tipocliente" ASC NULLS LAST, 
       "dim_cliente"."a1_ibge" ASC NULLS LAST, 
       "dim_cliente"."a1_cod" ASC NULLS LAST, 
       "dim_cliente"."a1_nome" ASC NULLS LAST;
-- this query took 37249.268 ms
```

Query Plan when not using trim

```
                                                                          QUERY PLAN                                                                           
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Group  (cost=170417.48..184027.84 rows=907357 width=129) (actual time=36649.329..37235.158 rows=43615 loops=1)
   Output: dim_cliente.tipocliente, dim_cliente.a1_ibge, dim_cliente.a1_cod, dim_cliente.a1_nome, dim_vendedor.a3_nome
   ->  Sort  (cost=170417.48..172685.88 rows=907357 width=129) (actual time=36649.315..36786.760 rows=907357 loops=1)
         Output: dim_cliente.tipocliente, dim_cliente.a1_ibge, dim_cliente.a1_cod, dim_cliente.a1_nome, dim_vendedor.a3_nome
         Sort Key: dim_cliente.tipocliente, dim_cliente.a1_ibge, dim_cliente.a1_cod, dim_cliente.a1_nome, dim_vendedor.a3_nome
         Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 265592kB
         ->  Hash Join  (cost=856.30..80628.56 rows=907357 width=129) (actual time=26.719..1593.693 rows=907357 loops=1)
               Output: dim_cliente.tipocliente, dim_cliente.a1_ibge, dim_cliente.a1_cod, dim_cliente.a1_nome, dim_vendedor.a3_nome
               Hash Cond: (fato_ventas_productos.key_vendedor = dim_vendedor.key_vendedor)
               ->  Hash Join  (cost=830.02..68126.13 rows=907357 width=86) (actual time=25.980..1203.775 rows=907357 loops=1)
                     Output: dim_cliente.tipocliente, dim_cliente.a1_ibge, dim_cliente.a1_cod, dim_cliente.a1_nome, fato_ventas_productos.key_vendedor
                     Hash Cond: (fato_ventas_productos.key_cliente = dim_cliente.key_cliente)
                     ->  Seq Scan on public.fato_ventas_productos  (cost=0.00..46880.57 rows=907357 width=16) (actual time=0.004..680.283 rows=907357 loops=1)
                           Output: fato_ventas_productos.key_cliente, fato_ventas_productos.key_vendedor
                     ->  Hash  (cost=618.90..618.90 rows=16890 width=86) (actual time=25.931..25.931 rows=16890 loops=1)
                           Output: dim_cliente.tipocliente, dim_cliente.a1_ibge, dim_cliente.a1_cod, dim_cliente.a1_nome, dim_cliente.key_cliente
                           Buckets: 2048  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 1980kB
                           ->  Seq Scan on public.dim_cliente  (cost=0.00..618.90 rows=16890 width=86) (actual time=0.005..13.736 rows=16890 loops=1)
                                 Output: dim_cliente.tipocliente, dim_cliente.a1_ibge, dim_cliente.a1_cod, dim_cliente.a1_nome, dim_cliente.key_cliente
               ->  Hash  (cost=18.90..18.90 rows=590 width=59) (actual time=0.715..0.715 rows=590 loops=1)
                     Output: dim_vendedor.a3_nome, dim_vendedor.key_vendedor
                     Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 56kB
                     ->  Seq Scan on public.dim_vendedor  (cost=0.00..18.90 rows=590 width=59) (actual time=0.024..0.405 rows=590 loops=1)
                           Output: dim_vendedor.a3_nome, dim_vendedor.key_vendedor
 Total runtime: 37249.268 ms
(25 filas)
```

Is anything that I can do to solve this problem?

Here the link with a dump of the tables
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bwupj61i9BtWZ1NiVXltaWc0dnM/view?usp=sharing

I have tested in postgres 9.3 and 9.4 the result is the same.

Comment: Unrelated, but: `work_mem = 16GB` is **way** to high. This memory can be allocated by *each* sort (or hashing) step in a query. Every query can request this amount of memory **multiple** times. It's not an overall limit to be shared by all queries.

Comment: the problem is that if I put the trim in any column that is in the order by it use hashaggregate I have try creating index with all the columns using in order by, and running analyze but don't solve the problem

Comment: The output of `explain (analyze, verbose)` would be more helpful.

Comment: When I can will put the output of that command thanks

Comment: But the real question is: why would you want to trim "dim_cliente"."tipocliente". This column appears to be a variable from a strong domain (and probably a low cardinality) , which should not allow multiple ways to express the same (semantic) value.

Comment: I don't want and I can't is just to show the diference in the Query Plan

Comment: I want the performance of the query with the trim

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I have put the output of the `explain (analyze, verbose)` and a link with the dump of tables that involves the query I appreciate your help